# Why doesn't the CientScript.RegisterStartupScript method call the javascript function in Firefox?

Tags: c#, asp.net, registerstartupscript, registerclientscriptblock

I have a code in which I am calling the javascript function from the cs(codebehind) file using the `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` method.

Though, this works in *Google Chrome* and *Internet Explorer*, it doesn't work in **Firefox** (even the latest one FF 61). But, when i replace the function name with the whole function as it is, it works in Firefox.

I have tried using all the possible alternatives `Page.ClientScript`, `ClientScriptBlock`, `RegisterStartupScriptBlock` etc., only in vain.

Kindly help me.

*P.S*: I hope I made my question clear.

Comment: Use some javascript degugger like firebug or the browser, and check if there are any errors in your javascript

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but the control doesnt come to the javacript function from the code behind file, while working with firefox, it does however in chrome and internet explorer and also if there were any errors, i wouldnt get the desired result in chrome or internet explorer right ?

Comment: Please post your entire relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

Check that your javascript function call is being launched when your page has been rendered completly.

The script you are registering  in

> ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript

Should be decorated inside a snippet like this:

```
string script= @"window.onload = function(){
  // your call to the function...
};"
```